# Uploading MVC to Filezilla

Tags: model-view-controller, filezilla

When I run my application, the link is:

```
http://localhost:1234/Account/LogOn
```

But when I upload it to Filezilla, I go:

```
http://0.0.0.0/Account/LogOn
```

and it says "The resource cannot be found."

Which is the correct path?

Comment: You're trying to use filezilla to request a MVC controller?

Comment: We can't possibly know.  Based on the mention of "MVC" in the question title/tags, I'm assuming this isn't actually a "path" but instead a route for the web server/application to translate into some kind of server resource.  (You don't mention the technology, so I can't be more specific.)  You're going to have to check your web application configuration, check the server logs, do some debugging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Account/LogOn directory is inside the root folder or whatever folder is used as the root folder. Also ensure that you have read/write access to the files once uploaded.